# How to Delete Color Stops of Color Ramp using Python

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, shaders

I have Added a Color ramp in my node editor using a Script
 and I wan't that the Color Stops That Are Available by default Should be Deleted.
before I add new stops 
I know how to add new stops but i don't Know how to remove the stops that are there by default using Python script.
Can Anyone Help me Out Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove them but not the last one.

If `cr_node` is the color ramp node, stops are stored in `cr_node.color_ramp.elements`.

You can remove the element `n` by:

```
cr_node.color_ramp.elements.remove( cr_node.color_ramp.elements[n] )
```

But if you attempt to remove the last one, you will have this error message:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Element not found in element collection or **last element**
```

So you need to keep it and change its values:

```
cr_node.color_ramp.elements[0].color = your color
cr_node.color_ramp.elements[0].position = your position
```